# Using scanf to skip N white spaces

Tags: c, scanf

Im trying to read an input in the format (int,int) in which there could be N white spaces between the beggining and the 1st ( , ( and the 1st int, between the 1st int and the comma and so on till the end where could also be N white spaces between ) and the end of input.

ex: `$ _(  int,     int )___ .` read `_` as whitespace.

So far i had this but it is not working:

```
scanf("%*[](%*[]%d%*[],%*[]%d%*[])%*[])")
```

where my `%*[]` would be used to ignore white spaces.

Could anybody help me?

Comment: If you want a parser, write a parser.

Comment: Regular expressions would be more suited to this.

Comment: Using scanf is a requirement of this problem.

Comment: Are you just trying to parse the two ints or the stuff around them as well?

Comment: Im just trying to catch the two ints. The ( , ) is the way the input is, why?

Comment: Did you try scanf("$ ( %d, %d ) ", ... ? scanf is pretty happy to skip over whitespace.

Comment: `"%*[]"` does _not_ ignore white spaces.  `"%*[](%*[]"` says to consume `']'`, `'('`, `'%'`, `'*'`, `'['` chatterers.  `"%*[ ]"` does consume spaces, but only spaces, not all white-spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `scanf("%*[ ](%*[ ]%d%*[ ],%*[ ]%d%*[ ])%*[ ]",&a,&b);` where `a` and `b` are the two integers. In your question the part with integer variables is missing.

Answer (score 0):

scanf() and sscanf() want to skip white spaces in general.  One white space in the formatting is enough to specify it.  Because you only care about the two ints, you don't need to give scanf() any information about what's after the second int.  If it's acceptable, just start looking at `line` from the whitespace just past the first `(` and then up to the last int.  Here's an example using some 'pointer magic' where `line` is a char buffer and isn't testing to see if there's anything at ptr+1:

```
char *ptr = 0;
int x = 0, y = 0, n = 0;

for( ptr = line; *ptr; p++ )
    if( *ptr == '(' ) break;
n = sscanf( ptr+1, " %d, %d", &x, &y );
```

n will contain the number of fields assigned (which should be two in this case) and x and y are the two ints you're interested in.

Similary, to use scanf(), you can catch and throw away the first part:

```
n = scanf( "%s ( %d, %d", garbage, &x, &y );
```

where garbage is a char buffer that's big enough which you never have to look at.  n would be 3 in this case.

Answer (score 0):

`"%*[]"` does *not* ignore white spaces.  `"%*[](%*[]"` says to consume `']'`, `'('`, `'%'`, `'*'`, `'['` characters.

```
//  v---v  scanset
"%*[](%*[]"
```

`"%*[ ]"` does consume spaces, but only spaces, not all white-spaces.

Use `" "` to to ignore all white spaces (including `'\n'`).

---

Given the format `$ _( int, int )___ .` where `_` is an arbitrary amount of white-space use

```
int n = 0;
int result = scanf(" $ (%d ,%d ) .%n", &int1, &int2, &n);
if ((result != 2) || (n == 0)) {
  ; // failed, handle error.
}
```

Let's break the scanf() format down

`" "` match 0 to unlimited number of white-space.
`"$"`  match a `'$'`
`"("`  match `'('`
`"%d"` match any amount of leading white-space, then look for an `int`, storing in the corresponding `int *`.
`","`  match `','`
`")"`  match `')'`
`"."`  match `'.'`
`"%n"` Save the number of `char` parsed so far into the corresponding `int *`.  Acting on this directive does not affect the `scanf()` result.

Liberal use of `%n` could be intersperse should more specific scanning be require than suggested in this solution.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an OLD question now, but it still is found in searches. I stumbled upon it looking for something else and was surprised that there was no simple correct answer yet.

Assuming N is not a specific number of spaces, a format string to use is " (%d%1s%d )"
Breaking it down,

- " " scans 0 or more whitespace characters
- "(" matches the opening parenthesis
- "%d" reads the first integer, skipping any whitespace before it
- "%1s" skips any whitespace before the comma and reads a 1-character string, which should be a comma
- "%d" reads the second integer, again skipping whitespace
- " " scans 0 or more whitespace characters
- ")" matches the closing parenthesis

Below is a sample program using sscanf(), which takes the same format strings as fprintf().

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    const char tests[] =
        "(1,2)"
        "(3, 4   )"
        "  (   5 , 6   )"
        "  (7 ,8)"
    ;

    const char *string_to_scan = tests;
    for ( ;  ; ) {
        int n1, n2;
        int n_char_read;
        char s[2];
        const int rc_scan = sscanf(string_to_scan, " (%d%1s%d )%n",
                &n1, s, &n2, &n_char_read);
        if (rc_scan == EOF) { /* End of string reached */
            break;
        }
        if (rc_scan != 3 || *s != ',') {
            (void) fprintf(stderr, "Scan error!\n");
            break;
        }
        (void) fprintf(stdout, "Read %d characters. n1=%d and n2=%d\n",
                n_char_read, n1, n2);
        string_to_scan += n_char_read;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Read 5 characters. n1=1 and n2=2
Read 9 characters. n1=3 and n2=4
Read 15 characters. n1=5 and n2=6
Read 8 characters. n1=7 and n2=8
```

Note that %n is used to step through the test string. It is important to use %1s rather than %s in the format string to prevent a buffer overrun if a malformed string like (1,,2) is read.

An alternative that is slightly more complex but more compact uses [,] to scan only for a comma between the numbers and does not assign it to any variable using * suppression. Note here that a leading space is required before the specifier with [,] to skip any leading spaces, which would not happen automatically as it would with a %s.

```
int main(void) {
    const char tests[] =
        "(1,2)"
        "(3, 4   )"
        "  (   5 , 6   )"
        "  (7 ,8)"
    ;

    const char *string_to_scan = tests;
    for ( ;  ; ) {
        int n1, n2;
        int n_char_read;
        const int rc_scan = sscanf(string_to_scan, " (%d %*1[,]%d )%n",
                &n1, &n2, &n_char_read);
        if (rc_scan == EOF) { /* End of string reached */
            break;
        }
        if (rc_scan != 2) {
            (void) fprintf(stderr, "Scan error!\n");
            break;
        }
        (void) fprintf(stdout, "Read %d characters. n1=%d and n2=%d\n",
                n_char_read, n1, n2);
        string_to_scan += n_char_read;
    }
}
```